# Angular 7 module css not being added to head element

Tags: angular, angular7, ngx-spinner

we have a few angular webapps and are currently on angular 7.
In 2 of them I have added ngx-spinner and setup it up per the readme and it works without issue.
However, on the 3rd app it does not load the css into the <head> element.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner

[image: Working versiIon]

In the image you can see the style for ngx-spinner in the <head>.
The version that does not work has all the other expected styles just not this one.

There are no special imports for the styles and in the working versions I do not import the styles.

The versions of the packages between the working and non working apps are just about identical.
I looked through about everything I can think of and do not see something different in the setup or config.

What are some things that could cause this?

Comment: Any advice about where to even start looking for the cause would be helpful.  If any more info is needed please let me know. I just do not  know what is relevant in this case.

Comment: I faced the same problem

Comment: @Tagi  am starting to think it has to do with the typescript target and module.  The other apps are on es2015 but due to some older deps in this one it is still on es5.